# Enable Firebase Crashlytics on an existing iOS app with manual Integration of Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I have an iOS app that had Firebase integrated in it using the manual way. This manual integration did not have Crashlytics Integration. Since it was an older Firebase version(v 4.0). I replaced it with the latest one(v 8.4.1).

- I havent replaced the Google-Service Info.plist
- In Firebase documentation, it says "Enable Crashlytics". There is no
  such button    in Firebase console anywhere. Please check it out
  [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=ios).

Currently, the integration is successful, it also prints my crashlytics version in logs but I have simulated around 20 crashes and FIREBASE CONSOLE SHOWS NONE.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics may depend on more recent changes to the `Google-Service Info.plist` format. Does downloading and integrating the `Google-Service Info.plist` from the console make a difference?

Comment: Replaced the Google-Service Info.plist but no change. It shouldn't matter if you ask me.

Comment: The Xcode debugger prevents Crashlytics from collecting crashes. When testing, did you stop Xcode like mentioned here? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=ios#force-test-crash